# how to create a shortcut to open a folder in file explorer and sort

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

To create a shortcut in windows that when executed, will open a folder in file explorer (e.g. `c:\mysql`) is simple.

But is it possible to make it also automatically sort by a particular property (e.g. sorted by the date modified, descending)?

Comment: you would have to create a bat file that would do both 'first sort then opening the folder)

Comment: @KahnKah mind elaborate how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify windows version, but I'm assuming you are using Windows 10.

AFAIK, the Windows 10 file explorer remembers the sort method per directory by default. I don't think you need a specific script for that. Just click on the column you want to sort and it should remember that for that particular directory.

Comment: Actually , I’d like to have diff shortcut with different sorting